# Do .pyc files in Python contain mnemonics

Tags: python, implementations

I'm interested for some time in CPython implementation of Python. I understand that .pyc files contain serialized bytecode, including opcodes. However do these files contain mnemonics? I think that interpreter could use just opcodes. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, bytecode files do not contain mnemonics.

Mnemonics are *textual* representations for instructions of a (virtual/bytecode) processor and are an integral part of assembly languages.
Bytecode files are not meant to be read by humans and thus are typically binary files that directly contain the machine-code (binary) instructions for the bytecode processor.